# Update query on temporary table in Linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, linqpad

Hey guys I am new in Linq and I am trying to convert stored procedures. But I am having a hard time writing update query in LINQ my query in SP is like

```
 UPDATE @tempTable1
 SET someColumn = 1
 FROM @tempTable1 p, @tempTable2 t2, NonTempTable nt
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
   AND t1.id = nt.id
   AND nt.status = 'abcd';
```

I wrote following conversion of above query in LINQ

```
 var Obj = (from t1 in temp1
            join t2 in tmp2 on t1.id equals t2.id
            join nt in NonTempTable on t2.id equals nt.id
            where nt.status == "abcd"
            select t1).First();
 Obj.somecolumn = 1;                     
 Obj.SubmitChanges();
```

But I am gettimg following error

```
Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.ProcedureID' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

I just have database of my application and I am trying to convert stored procedures into LINQ using LINQPad

Can anyone tell me  how to write above query to Linq? What more do I need to do this?

Comment: sumit: Do *not* create any more accounts in order to post more duplicates of this question.

Comment: _I am trying convert stored procedures into LINQ._ Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a workaround for my above question which is following

```
var Obj = (from t1 in temp1
        join t2 in tmp2 on t1.id equals t2.id
        join nt in NonTempTable on t2.id equals nt.id
        where nt.status == "abcd"
        select t1).First();

var anatherObj = (from o in Obj
                  select new { o.nonUpdatedColumn1, o.nonUpdatedColumn2, o.nonUpdatedColumn3, o.someColumn = 1});
```

And got the updated temporary table in "anatherObj"

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an entity from your tempTable1, tempTable2 and NonTempTable. Then you should be able to work with the data from these tables by means of Linq. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362.aspx how to create models.

After you create it, you can update your records or proper record and save changes to database

```
 var result = (from row in model.JoinedTable
         where row.status == "abcd"
         select row).First();
 result.someColumn = "1";
 model.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response, but we are not using entity Framwork, we are using LinkPad for writing LINQ querries. Can you please tell me How can I write above querry without using entity framework

Comment: @sumitjoshi Well, you can't. If you don't use linq to entity, you data in client side and database is not connected. In such case you can use only LINQ to Objects to operate with data on client side, but these changes would not affect on server side.

Comment: Thanks again, however I just wanted to ask you that I am trying to convert all stored procedures to LINQ and I do not have the Application code, just the database from which I am trying to convert using LINQ, can I do this while having just the database not application code? It would be great if you help me on this one

Comment: @sumitjoshi I'm bit cofused about what you are trying to do. Can you update your question and show, where and into what you are expecting to convert you proc (without appliaction code). Do you use CLR assemblies in your RDB?

Comment: Thanks again, I have edited my question with I did? and I am not using CLR assemblies

Comment: Ah, LinqPad, why didn't you say that before. You should turn on statements mode to make update queries. See squaredroot.com/2007/12/05/addupdatedelete-with-linqpad

Answer (score 0):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*.  In order to *update* data you need to choose a framework (or find out what the main project team is using) that is designed to do that - Entity Framework, LinqToSQL, or plain old ADO.NET (`SQlCommand` + `SqlConnection`, etc.).

There is no built-in mechanism within Linq to update data in memory, let alone propagate changes to a data source.  Even with Entity Framework - you *can* use Linq to *get* the object(s) you want to update, but the actual updating does not use Linq at all, just property setters and methods like `SaveChanges()` which you have in your example.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me is there another way to accomplish the logic. I am looking for a conversion of logic not a conversion of exact steps that the sp took. The data needs to be right at the end but exact steps do not need to be replicated.

Comment: The logic you have is fine - based on the error you're getting you haven't pasted the exact code (or it's happening in a different place)  because you haven't created any anonymous types.